# Does the ending of Ready Player Two mean what I think for Ready Player One?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018, ready-player-two

Does the ending mean that both stories are

> told from the digital copy point of view? And that Wade has seen the memories that are not his that are used in that novel?

It has been a little bit since I have read the first book but that would explain how they

> know what was going on with the Sixers in some parts of the first book.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that the first book was told from an AI point of view. I think it was supposed to be from a real-world perspective, and would stand alone quite well without a sequel.

Even RP2 was told almost completely from a first-person perspective up until the last chapter, when the narration started referring to "me" and "Wade" as separate entities. Up until that point, Parzival was simply an avatar with no self-awareness.

While Wade's ONI file did have his mental backup, and therefore his doppelganger, in the server it wasn't until he finished assembling The Siren that he was given the power to actually create one. Up until that point, everything was from a real-world memory perspective.